# Angular - How to get value from datepicker?

Tags: html, angular

I need to get `datepicker` value from user. However, I couldn't get the value.

My HTML datepicker:

```
<div ngbDropdown autoClose="outside" #startFilter="ngbDropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-filter date" id="startDate" ngbDropdownToggle>
        {{startDate | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'}}
        <div class="ipe-icon-calendar"></div>
    </button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="startDate">
        <ngb-datepicker [(ngModel)]="startDate" formControlName="fromDate" [startDate]="{ year: startDate.year(), month: startDate.month() + 1 }"
                            (select)="startFilter.close()" ></ngb-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
<div ngbDropdown autoClose="outside" #endFilter="ngbDropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-filter date" id="endDate" ngbDropdownToggle>
        {{endDate | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'}}
        <div class="ipe-icon-calendar"></div>
    </button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="endDate">
            <ngb-datepicker [(ngModel)]="endDate" formControlName="endDate" [startDate]="{ year: endDate.year(), month: endDate.month() + 1 }"
                    (select)="endFilter.close()"></ngb-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

My component:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
        fromDate:[''],
        endDate:['']
})

from = this.form.get('fromDate').value;
to = this.form.get('endDate').value;
```

But the value returns empty, pls help to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `formControls` in a `formGroup` aswell.

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="form">
  <div ngbDropdown autoClose="outside" #startFilter="ngbDropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-filter date" id="startDate" ngbDropdownToggle>
          {{startDate | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'}}
          <div class="ipe-icon-calendar"></div>
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="startDate">
          <ngb-datepicker formControlName="fromDate"
                      (select)="startFilter.close()" ></ngb-datepicker>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div ngbDropdown autoClose="outside" #endFilter="ngbDropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-filter date" id="endDate" ngbDropdownToggle>
          {{endDate | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'}}
          <div class="ipe-icon-calendar"></div>
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="endDate">
              <ngb-datepicker formControlName="endDate" 
                      (select)="endFilter.close()"></ngb-datepicker>
      </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
        fromDate: new FormControl(startDate),
        endDate: new FormControl(endDate)
})
```

Comment: Idem comment to @Silvio

Comment: adding form group makes the datepicker unable to change its date

Comment: Remove `ngModel` and initialize `formControl`s with start and end date. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `formControlName="fromDate"` and `formControlName="endDate"` you should Wrap it in a FormGroup.

```js
 this.form = this.fb.group({
    fromDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate
  })
```

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <div ngbDropdown autoClose="outside" #startFilter="ngbDropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-filter date" id="startDate" ngbDropdownToggle>
       {{startDate | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'}}
       <div class="ipe-icon-calendar"></div>
     </button>
     <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="startDate">
      <ngb-datepicker formControlName="fromDate" (select)="startFilter.close()" ></ngb-datepicker>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div ngbDropdown autoClose="outside" #endFilter="ngbDropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-filter date" id="endDate" ngbDropdownToggle>
       {{endDate | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'}}
       <div class="ipe-icon-calendar"></div>
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="endDate">
       <ngb-datepicker formControlName="endDate" (select)="endFilter.close()"></ngb-datepicker>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: `endDate` control is not inside the form.

Comment: Don't use together [(ngModel)] and formControlName. It use Reactive Form ONLY formControlName, if use Template Driven Form ONLY [(ngModel)]

Comment: adding `formgroup` makes the datepicker unable to change its date

Comment: @ritaj thanks for that comment. I didn't realize that these are two different divs.

Comment: As @Eliseo said you should remove the [(ngModels)]. you can initialize the start and endDate in the formControl.

Comment: just solved the problem , using formgroup must have `<form>` tag

Answer (score 1):

```
                      <input
                      class="form-control"
                      type="text"
                      ngbDatepicker
                      placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                      #d="ngbDatepicker"
                      formControlName="birthDate"
                      (click)="d.toggle()"
                      [readonly]="true"
                      [minDate]="{ year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1 }"
                      [maxDate]="{
                        year: new Date().getFullYear() + 1,
                        month: 12,
                        day: 31
                      }"
                    />
```

You can use formControlName for get value from datepicker like above